# Infinite sidebar with infinite scroll

Tags: jquery, ajax, infinite-scroll, sidebar, sticky

I have been trying to create a sidebar that is similar to mydomaine.com it dynamically creates a sticky sidebar through the infinite scroll. the problem is when my sidebar is generated the old sidebar doesn't stick to the bottom of the previous container so both of them jump up as well or the new sidebar doesn't append to the document, here's the code, I've been racking my brain around it:

```
(function($) {
var element = $('.follow-scroll'),
    originalY = element.offset().top;

// Space between element and top of screen (when scrolling)
var topMargin = 20;

// Should probably be set in CSS; but here just for emphasis
element.css('position', 'relative');

$(window).on('scroll', function(event) {
    var scrollTop = $(window).scrollTop();

    element.stop(false, false).animate({
        top: scrollTop < originalY
                ? 0
                : scrollTop - originalY + topMargin
    }, 300);
```

Comment: Can you post your html as well or do a JSFiddle to illustrate the problem.

Comment: Thank you for the quick response, after searching a lot, i found this fiddle with the right concept, the only problem is that I need a breaking point between the sidebars, not just z-index http://jsfiddle.net/66MBH/6/